# What is this arrow and number in the status bar?

Tags: atom-editor

While doing a find and replace today a large arrow flashed up on the screen and disappeared a few seconds later.

Now there is an up arrow icon and a number in the status bar at the bottom of the screen, what are these?

[image: Picture of status bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two separate things.

[image]

The big flashing arrow when you use find is to indicate that it has reached the bottom of the buffer and has returned to the top.

The small arrow in the status bar: [image: Status bar] indicates that your repository is one commit ahead of upstream.

There is also an arrow for commits behind upstream:

[image]